# I have created a MapReduce job in Eclipse. I face the following error on running it. No errors are there in code

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

```
14/06/30 19:08:08 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
14/06/30 19:08:08 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/06/30 19:08:08 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:Anish Gupta (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chmod": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chmod": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.execCommand(RawLocalFileSystem.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:524)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:888)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:882)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:882)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:556)
    at numbersum.NumberDriver.main(NumberDriver.java:34)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Are you using Windows? Please provide more information. A stacktrace wall as the only content of your question will not get you a quick answer, if one at all

Comment: yes im using windows. Latest edition of eclipse (eclipse luna).

Comment: What's the process in which you built/installed hadoop, with or without cygwin? And what version of Hadoop?

Comment: I just added the jar files to the build path. I am using cdh3u5 version of Hadoop. I attempted to install cygwin but I'm facing problem with it so it's not installed as yet.

Comment: Follow one of these tutorials. [For newer 2.2](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows) and for older [0.2x verions](http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/00%20-%20Intro.html). I prefer the newer version. You need to follow the directions exactly. Even using Windows SDK command line. The problem is you don't have the native hadoop. If you build it correctly from the link, you should have hadoop.dll and when you run in eclipse you need to make sure you have a HADOOP_HOME var pointing to the install bin

Comment: Edit last comment: HADOOP_HOME should point to the install, not the bin